# Find rows with consecutive ones

Tags: sql, oracle

I've two integer columns and need to display the rows with consecutive one's in the `NUM` column.

**Sample data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, NUM ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID  NUM
--  ---
 1    1
 2    1
 3    1
```

Comment: Why not 6-2 and 7-2 as well? They are consecutive too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using self-joins and achieved the result:

```
WITH TAB (ID, NUM) AS
(
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.ID,
    T.NUM
FROM
    TAB T
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            T1.ID   ID1,
            T2.ID   ID2,
            T1.NUM,
            COUNT(1) OVER(
                PARTITION BY T1.NUM
            ) RN
        FROM
            TAB T1
            JOIN TAB T2 ON ( T1.NUM = T2.NUM
                             AND T1.ID = T2.ID + 1 )
    ) T_IN ON ( ( T.ID = T_IN.ID1
                  OR T.ID = T_IN.ID2 )
                AND T.NUM = T_IN.NUM
                AND RN >= 2 ) -- THIS CONDITION IS TO RESTRICT CONSECUTIVES LESS THAN 3
ORDER BY
    1
```

**output:**

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5081073badf5dfd7148855cca5b5a815)

Comment: If there is a single row (non-consecutive) where `num = 1` and then later a run of consecutive ones then this will not find the consecutive ones. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c4935abafb91eb0acdb928cab68066c4)

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic functions `LAG` or `LEAD`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, NUM ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT id,num
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         num,
         LAG(  num ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS prev_num,
         LEAD( num ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS next_num
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE num = 1
AND   (  num = prev_num
      OR num = next_num )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | NUM
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  2 |   1
>  3 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6bdd7870412a96732e1f83dca67490a4)*